# Не могу разобраться с setTimeout();

Tags: javascript

Есть функция func(), её надо запустить **n** раз в цикле с интервалом в секунду, пробовал так

```
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
 setTimeout(func, 1000);
};
```

этот код запускает func() **n раз через секунду**, а мне нужен последовательный запуск с задержкой в секунду (т.е. запускается func() проходит секунда, запускается func() и так n раз.)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
  setTimeout(func, 1000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Вариант 1 - рекурсией
const recursion = (max, count = 1) => {
  count <= max && setTimeout(fun, 1000, max, count+1)
}

//вариант 2 - через интервал.
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
console.log('interval')
}, 1000)

setTimeout(()=>clearInterval(interval), 5000)
```